# Install bigquery on mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery, osx-mavericks

```
boo$ bq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/bq", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 3007, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 728, in require

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
    ``resolve()`` method. The `fallback` flag indicates whether we should
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pytz>=2010
```

Here is information:

```
boo$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
boo$ uname -a
Darwin boo-MacBook-Air.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

boo$ which bq
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/bq
boo$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
boo$ ls
Headers     Python      bin     lib
Mac     Resources   include     share
boo$ find . -name pkg_resources.py
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.4-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py
```

I don't know why `bq` try to access `pkg_resources.py` in `bdist.macosx-10.6-intel`. my system is 10.9.

Comment: It looks like you've installed some third-party Python 2.7, in such a way that it's got site-packages in /Library/Frameworks not shared with Apple's pre-installed 2.7.5, but other stuff shared. This is a recipe for disaster. Unless you really need two different Python 2.7s for some reason, the simplest thing to do is to uninstall the extra Python you installed, clean out the site-packages, and reinstall the packages you need with Apple's pre-installed Python. See [Sticking with Apple's Python 2.7](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/sticking-with-apples-python-27.html) for more info.

Comment: How can I do it and being able to run after that numpy, scipy and all the dozens modules I installed along the years?

Comment: Install them all for Apple's Python. Having a SciPy that you installed three years ago under OS X 10.7 that's linked to libraries that have been upgraded twice along the way is likely to cause a whole set of other problems anyway… Not to mention that there have been huge improvements to the library since then.

Comment: If you really insist on keeping two Python 2.7's around, you will have to learn what paths they use and how all these things work in Unix and specifically in OS X so you can debug this stuff yourself. And I don't think you want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two different Python 2.7 installations that share part of their site-packages.

In particular, OS X 10.9 comes with a Python 2.7.5 in `/usr/bin/python`. You've got a *different* Python 2.7.x in `/usr/local/bin/python`. You've got some stuff installed for one, some for the other, and some for both.

So, when you run `bq`, it may be running with `/usr/bin/python` and therefore not finding prerequisites that only exist for `/usr/local/bin/python`, or it may be running with `/usr/local/bin/python` and therefore not finding prerequisites that only exist for `/usr/bin/python`. You haven't given us enough information to be sure of which of these cases is true.

The easy way to fix this is to not have two different Python 2.7 installations around. It's not impossible to make things work, but you have to know what you're doing, and be careful, and know how to debug all the problems that arise, and you wouldn't be here if that were you. So, unless you have a very good reason to need a second Python 2.7, the fix is simple:

- Uninstall the extra Python 2.7. (The way to do that depends on how you installed it—python.org installer, Homebrew, an extra-batteries package like Enthought, custom build, …)
- Wipe out your site-packages. (When you run `/usr/bin/python` and `print sys.path`, it'll show you all the directories that site packages could be stored in.)
- Reinstall everything you need. (You may want to make a list of what you're erasing while you do it.)

[Sticking with Apple's Python 2.7](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/sticking-with-apples-python-27.html) explains the reasons not to have two Python 2.7 builds in more details—and also lists the exceptions when you *need* to do it.

---

As a side issue:

> I don't know why bq try to access pkg_resources.py in bdist.macosx-10.6-intel. my system is 10.9.

This means that your second Python was built to work on any OS X 10.6 or later (as opposed to Apple's preinstalled version that came with 10.9, which will only work on 10.9). That's not a problem. (In fact, if you're planning to create redistributable binary applications with, e.g., `py2app`, it's *necessary*.)

Comment: I think I will symbolic link all the bins and share them between both version.

Comment: @0x90: That's a good idea if you want to get lots of segfaults, but not if you want things to work…

Comment: BTW, I think now I figure out why I get this segmentation fault while `lldb` python, and running `import re; exit()`. 

`0x00000001002eff97 readline.so call_readline + 647, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) frame #0: 0x00000001002eff97 readline.so`

Comment: thanks for pointing up the facts, finally I reinstalled the 2.7.6, and both `bq` and the `numpy`, `scipy` etc. work. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `abarnert` I was aware that python.org published a 2.7.6 version, and Apple adopt the 2.7.5 version in their 10.9 distribution.

instead of uninstalling the third party python, I checked with what tool I had installed the third party (brew/port/wget the tar file and installing) originally and then I reinstalled the python 2.7.6 using the same tool, and all works.